# how to turn a .wpress file to a .sql file and view its contents?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, extension-methods

I want to move my wordpress database to cloud sql but I exported the wpress database as a file and its extension is .wpress. How can I change it to a .sql file and view its contents?

Answer (score 0):

### Two Options, covering all OS's:

1. Using Node.js under **any OS** :

   - Open your command prompt and go to the folder where you have your ".wpress" file;
   - Run this command (change the "**file_name**" for the name of your file)...

     `npx wpress-extract file_name.wpress`
   - If you get any confirmation prompt, just press "y" for yes;
   - A new folder will be created where you can find all the contents;
   - Inside the new folder you will find the ".sql" file.
2. Without Node.js only for **Windows or Mac**:

   - Get an excecutable extractor from [here](https://github.com/fifthsegment/Wpress-Extractor) and follow the instructions;
   - A new folder will be created where you can find all the contents;
   - Inside the new folder you will find the ".sql" file.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a WordPress developer but I might suggest you export the .wpress data to excel or better still a .csv file

View the data that way or you could import the data back to an SQL database and view from there.